# Microsoft Access from php with odbc Error : (07002)

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to run my first php script that is connecting to my MS Access `.accdb` database.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$dbName = "G:/xampp/htdocs/1.accdb"; 
$nazwa_produktu = (string)$_POST["nazwa_produktu"];
$cena = (int)$_POST["cena"];
$ilosc = (int)$_POST["ilosc"];
$kategoria = (string)$_POST["kategoria"];
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
die("Access database file not found !");
}
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$sql = "INSERT INTO [produkty] (nazwa_produktu, cena, ilosc, kategoria) VALUES ($nazwa_produktu, $cena, $ilosc, $kategoria)";
if($conn->query($sql))
    {
       echo 'success';
    }else{

           $db_err = $conn->errorInfo();
           echo 'Error : ('. $db_err[0] .') -- ' . $db_err[2];
    }
```

I'm still getting:

> Error : (07002) -- [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:258)

Probably it has something to do with `Uid` and `Pwd` in `$conn` but I really have zero idea what can I do more, because when I try run this without this parameters there's still something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `Uid` as `Admin`, per [this reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/standard-security/), i.e.:

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=$dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
```

Comment: It's still the same.